# Problemas al ingresar datos en un tablelayout

Tags: android

Hola amigos del foro esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, les comento que estoy aprendiendo a ingresar datos en una table layout, el cual ingreso mi primea fila, ero al ingresar la segunda fila no lo realiza tal procedimiento, les comento además que soy nuevo en estas lides de android, favor de asesorarme en que estoy fallando, agredo el código de mi clase que utilizo:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TableDynamic {
private TableLayout tableLayout;
private Context context;
private String[] header;
private ArrayList<String[]> data;
private TableRow tableRow;
private TextView txtCell;
private int indexC;
private int indexR;
private boolean multiColor = false;
int firtColor, secondColor, textColor, colorLinea;

public TableDynamic(TableLayout tableLayout, Context context) {
    this.tableLayout = tableLayout;
    this.context = context;
}

public void addHeader(String[] header) {
    this.header = header;
    createHeader();
}

public void addData(ArrayList<String[]> data) {
    this.data = data;
    createDataTable();
}

private void newRow() {
    tableRow = new TableRow(context);
}

private void newCell() {
    txtCell = new TextView(context);
    txtCell.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    txtCell.setTextSize(18);
}

private void createHeader() {
    indexC = 0;
    newRow();
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        newCell();
        txtCell.setText(header[indexC++]);
        tableRow.addView(txtCell, newTableRowParams());
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
}

private void createDataTable() {
    String info;
    for(indexR=1;indexR<= data.size();indexR++) {
        newRow();
        for(indexC=0;indexC<header.length;indexC++) {
            newCell();
            String[] row = data.get(indexR-1);
            info = (indexC<row.length)?row[indexC]:"";
            txtCell.setText(info);
            tableRow.addView(txtCell,newTableRowParams());
        }
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
}

public void addItems(String[] item) {
    String info;
    data.add(item);
    indexC = 0;
    newRow();
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        newCell();
        info = (indexC < item.length) ? item[indexC++] : "";
        txtCell.setText(info);
        tableRow.addView(txtCell, newTableRowParams());
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow, data.size());//Se quito el -1 despues de size para corregir
    reColoring();
    reColoringLinea();
}

public void backgroundHeader(int color) {
    indexC = 0;
    //newRow();
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        txtCell = getCell(0, indexC++);
        txtCell.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
}

public void backgroundData(int firtColor, int secondColor) {
    for (indexR = 1; indexR <= data.size(); indexR++) {
        multiColor = !multiColor;
        for (indexC = 0; indexC < header.length; indexC++) {
            txtCell = getCell(indexR, indexC);
            txtCell.setBackgroundColor((multiColor) ? firtColor : secondColor);
        }
    }
    this.firtColor = firtColor;
    this.secondColor = secondColor;
}

public void lineColor(int color) {
    indexR = 0;
    while (indexR <= data.size()) {
        getRow(indexR++).setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
    this.colorLinea = color;
}

public void textColorData(int color) {
    for (indexR = 1; indexR <= data.size(); indexR++) {
        for (indexC = 0; indexC < header.length; indexC++) {
            getCell(indexR, indexC).setTextColor(color);
        }
    }
    this.textColor = color;
}

public void textColorHeader(int color) {
    indexC = 0;
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        getCell(0, indexC++).setTextColor(color);
    }
}

public void reColoring() {
    indexC = 0;
    multiColor=!multiColor;
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        txtCell = getCell(data.size(), indexC++);
        txtCell.setBackgroundColor((multiColor) ? firtColor : secondColor);
        txtCell.setTextColor(textColor);
    }
}

public void reColoringLinea(){
    indexR = 0;
    while (indexR <= data.size()) {
        getRow(indexR++).setBackgroundColor(colorLinea);
    }
}

private TableRow getRow(int index) {
    return (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(index);
}

private TextView getCell(int rowIndex, int columIndex) {
    tableRow = getRow(rowIndex);
    return (TextView) tableRow.getChildAt(columIndex);
}

private TableRow.LayoutParams newTableRowParams() {
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
    params.weight = 1;
    return params;
}
```

}

y este es el código en el mainactivity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText et_filas, et_tipo, et_marca, et_modelo;
Button ingresar, modificar;
TableLayout tbldatos;
private String[]header={"N° Filas","Tipo","Marca","Modelo"};
private ArrayList<String[]> rows=new ArrayList<>();
private TableDynamic tableDynamic;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et_filas = findViewById(R.id.txtitem);
    et_tipo = findViewById(R.id.txttipo);
    et_marca = findViewById(R.id.txtmarca);
    et_modelo = findViewById(R.id.txtmodelo);
    ingresar = findViewById(R.id.cmdingresar);
    modificar = findViewById(R.id.cmdmodificar);
    tbldatos = findViewById(R.id.tbldatos);

    tableDynamic = new TableDynamic(tbldatos, getApplicationContext());
    tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
    tableDynamic.addData(getClients());
    tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
    tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
    tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
    tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
    tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
}

private ArrayList<String[]> getClients(){

    return rows;
}

public void datos (View view){
    String[]item = new String[]{et_filas.getText().toString(),et_tipo.getText().toString(),et_marca.getText().toString(),et_modelo.getText().toString()};
    tableDynamic.addItems(item);
}
```

ojala que me puedan ayudar en que estoy fallando, que no me agrega la segunda fila, ya que quiero aprender dicha herramienta, y desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

ayer termine de revisar bien el código en la función backgroundHeader, esta en comentario el Newrow(), pero al cambiarlo me funciona bien al seguir ingresando las filas, si problema alguno, para que lo vean y puedan ocuparlo y disculpen las molestias.